# select option como paramentro para metodo codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver de forma alguma.
Tenho um form html que tem um select option preciso pegar o valor selecionado quando o form é enviado e utilizar como parâmetro para um método, existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia colocar o seu código para podermos lhe ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Há sim, amigo.
Supondo que o `name` do combobox é `consulta` ficaria assim no controller:

```
public funcition Consultar(){
$parametro = $this->input->post('consulta'); //formulário submetido via POST

/*lembrando que o valor que virá submetido pelo formulário 
é o que se encontra em value lá no html */

$this->load->model('Nome_da_tua_model');
$res = $this->Nome_da_tua_model->Teu_metodo_de_consulta($parametro);
}
```

Já na tua `model` ficaria assim:

```
public function Teu_metodo_de_consulta($parametro){
$this->db->Select('*');
$this->db->From('Tua_tabela');
if(!empty($parametro)){
$this->db->where('Tua_tabela.Teu_campo', $parametro);
}
$result = $this->db->get()->Result();
return $result;
}
```

Agora no controller a variável `$res` tem os dados da tua consulta.

O comando `SQL` que executei no trecho acima, é para valores iguais, caso seja necessário outro tipo de comparação, aconselho a ler a documentação no [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html).

Espero ter ajudado, Oss!

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito